# Javascript onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Q1: My point is create many buttons as many rows of array. Im having some erros here :s

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myArray = [];

$('#button').click(function(){

var value1 = $('#value1').val();
var value2 = $('#value1').val();
var value3 = $('#value1').val();
var newArray = []; 
var newArray[0] = value1;
var newArray[1] = value2;
var newArray[2] = value3;
myArray.push(newArray);

$("#save").append(
    $("<button>").click(function() {
        myFunction.apply(null, myArray);
    }).text("Click me!")
   );
   });

});

function myFunction(value1,value2,value3)
{
var jsonData = $.ajax({
url: "file.php?value1=" + value1 + "&value2=" + value2 + "&value3=" + value3
dataType: "json",
async: false
}).responseText;
(...)
}
//edited: problem maybe found. I said buttons dont do anything because of this.
OUTPUT: file.php?value1=paul,23,USA&value2=undefined&value3=undefined
//it seems that value1 gets all values :s
</script>


<div id ="save"></div>
```

Im looking for a solution that return someting like this:

eg:

```
<!--<button onclick="myFunction(name,age,country)">Click me</button>-->
<button onclick="myFunction(paul,23,USA)">Click me</button>
<button onclick="myFunction(john,23,USA)">Click me</button>
```

EDITED MY CODE WITH MORE DETAILS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because `myArray`'s first item is a array (`newArray`) you should call only one array parameter try call the function as below and it should work,

```
myFunction.apply(null, newArray);
//or
myFunction.apply(null, [value1,value2,value3]);
```

Comment: myFunction.apply(null, newArray); ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Guess this helps:

```
    <div  id="save">
    </div>      
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addButtons(myArray){
            for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++)
            {
                var button = $('<button id="btn_'+i+'" onclick="myFunction(this);">Click me</button>')
                $(button).data('details',myArray[i]).appendTo("#save");
            }
        }
        function myFunction(element){
            alert($(element).data('details'));
        }
    </script>
```